# Google Play: Developer Console: Have no access using company google domain email

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

I try to launch the first app for my company for the 1st time using the company google domain account, however, when I try to create a Google Play Developer Console account, but it doesn't let me do it with an error:

"We are sorry, but you do not have access to this service. Please contact your domain administrator for access."

I certainly want to publish the app using my work email. Any thought or guideline to follow?

Thanks,

Comment: Contact your domain administrator for access. Who created your company Google domain account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question regarding a specific account at an off-site, third-party vendor site. Contact that third-party vendor directly for support related to your account. We have no ability to access your account or address issues with it from here. We're not Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish any Android application on Google Play Store for your organization than you should publish it under Google play console account created using your company domain email address.

You need to create account follwing the steps:-

Registration Link: Click on –->

[Google Play Console Sign up](https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?biz=true&cc=IN&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fconsole%2Fdeveloper%2F&dsh=S-1593112312%3A1665204352791753&flowEntry=SignUp&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&ifkv=AQDHYWqH85RMlKxT53Lk0reSHw8_XJ6rKbR5mlu7jgOTYEqh8Dd5Cmuv3eLkFJv_NAN1TdKOHOh24g&service=androiddeveloper)

[image: Use the organization mail id to create a Google Account.]

[image: Click on “Use my current email address instead”.]

[image: Choose-> An organization]

[image: Fill the form with required details]